# Removing Python List Items that Contain 2 of the Same Elements

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list myList, which contains items of the form

```
myList = [('a','b',3), ('b','a',3), ('c','d',1), ('d','c',1), ('e','f',4)]
```

The first and second items are equal and so are the third and fourth, although their first and second elements are swapped. I would like to keep only one of each so that the final list looks like this:

a,b,3

c,d,1

e,f,4

Comment: (1) What types are your `a` and `b`?  Are they sortable and/or hashable (i.e. could you put them in a set)?  (2) Do you care about the output order?  If your myList were in the order (c,d,1), (a,b,3), would you need that ordering preserved in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If yo want to keep order of tuple, and always keep first tuple when there are *duplicates*, you can do :

```
>>> sets = [ frozenset(x) for x in myList ]
>>> filtered = [ myList[i] for i in range(len(myList)) if set(myList[i]) not in sets[:i] ]
>>> filtered
[('a', 'b', 3), ('c', 'd', 1), ('e', 'f', 4)]
```

If you prefer not to use another variable :

```
filtered = [ myList[i] for i in range(len(myList))
            if set(myList[i]) not in [ frozenset(x) for x in myList ][:i] ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use sets and frozensets to remove equal elements:

```
>>> mySet = [frozenset(x) for x in myList]
>>> [tuple(x) for x in set(mySet)]
[('a', 3, 'b'), (4, 'e', 'f'), (1, 'c', 'd')]
```

the result can then be sorted however you'd like.

Comment: If you might have duplicates in your tuples and you want each tuple to have the same number of each duplicate then @NJM 's answer will work better.

Answer (score 2):

Take each tuple in myList, convert it to a list and apply sorted(). This results in a list filled with sorted inner lists which would look like.

```
myList = [('a','b',3), ('b','a',3), ('c','d',1), ('d','c',1), ('e','f',4)]
sorted_inner_list = [sorted(list(element)) for element in myList]
output = list(set(map(tuple,sorted_inner_list)))
```

Comment: Sure, the first step I took was to take each tuple in myList, convert it to a list and apply `sorted()`. This results in a list filled with sorted inner lists which would look like: `[[3, 'a', 'b'], [3, 'a', 'b'], [1, 'c', 'd'], [1, 'c', 'd'], [4, 'e', 'f']]`. I then wanted to apply the `set()` function on this list of elements that now had repeated elements i.e. `[3,'a','b'] and [1,'c','d']`. However you can't apply `set()` to something mutable (unhashable) like a list. So I used the `map()` function to turn all elements into tuples which are hashable.

Comment: I should add though that @Michael's answer is much less kludgy.

Comment: awww.. NJM thanks. -- I was close to deleting my answer because I find yours better and more elegant! Well, now we have several responses to the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to maintain the order of your `tuples` inside `list` and eliminate the duplicates by using `set`

```
>>> myList = [('a','b',3), ('b','a',3), ('c','d',1), ('d','c',1), ('e','f',4)]
>>> _ = lambda item: ([str,int].index(type(item)), item)
>>> sorted(set([tuple(sorted(i, key = _)) for i in myList]), key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'b', 3), ('c', 'd', 1), ('e', 'f', 4)]
```